# How to relate objects which are subclassed from PFObject?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, parse-platform, pfobject

I have two classes person and address. These two classes are subclassed from PFObject. How can I make a relation between these classes? Below is the code:

```
Person:
@interface Person : PFObject<PFSubclassing>
@property(strong,nonatomic)NSString *lastName;

Address:
@interface Address : PFObject<PFSubclassing>
@property(strong,nonatomic)Person *person;
@property(strong,nonatomic)NSString *lastName;
```

In Address file, I have done this to make a relation but it shows me null value:
Both of them are created as singleton because I wanted to make relations.

```
address.person.lastName= person.lastName;
```

Please help me how to make the relation. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you do something like this? PFObject *comment = [PFObject objectWithClassName:kPAPActivityClassKey];
    [comment setObject:trimmedComment forKey:kPAPActivityContentKey]; // Set comment text
    [comment setObject:[self.photo objectForKey:kPAPPhotoUserKey] forKey:kPAPActivityToUserKey]; // Set toUser
    [comment setObject:[PFUser currentUser] forKey:kPAPActivityFromUserKey]; // Set fromUser
    [comment setObject:kPAPActivityTypeComment forKey:kPAPActivityTypeKey];
    [comment setObject:self.photo forKey:kPAPActivityPhotoKey];